# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "¡Qué pesado el abuelo cebolleta!"?

Tags: modismos, significado

He visto la frase `Qué pesao el abuelo cebolleta`, ¿qué significa? Nunca antes la había escuchado.

Me imagino que para aludir a una persona pesada, pero ¿`cebolleta`? También quería saber si es una frase ampliamente conocida, como en el lenguaje español, o en algún país, localidad, circulo de amigos... o simplemente no muy conocida. No parecía acabada de inventar cuando la escuché.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El abuelo cebolleta era un personaje de cómic (o tebeo), parte de [la familia Cebolleta](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_familia_Cebolleta).

El abuelo estaba siempre contando batallitas ("En mis tiempos bla bla bla..."), y de ahí viene la expresión: alguien te está aburriendo siempre con una "batallita", anécdota o historia aburrida, moralizante, etc.

> El abuelo Cebolleta, que con su enorme barba blanca y su **interminable verborrea** ("en cierta ocasión, iba yo al frente de mis cipayos, cuando, bla, bla, bla...."), se convertiría en uno de los más recordados de los personajes de Bruguera. Obsesionado con contar batallitas, **ha pasado al imaginario colectivo y a la lengua común a través de la frase hecha: "Cuentas más batallitas que el abuelo Cebolleta"**

[image: cebolleta]
[image]

Este tebeo se publicaba en España, donde como ves la expresión es más o menos popular, aunque no todo el mundo (hay que tener cierta edad para ello) pueda relacionar la expresión y el tebeo. Ignoro si esta influencia cultural ha transcendido a otros países de habla hispana.

Comment: La frase la escuche al companero @fedorqui, asi que supongo que ambos hayan vivido en Espana? o vivan por supuesto

Comment: Ahh, `tebeo`, gracias por la palabra. :)

Comment: @Theia jajaja, ¿me la leíste a mí? Sí, creo que aunque relativamente joven ya soy un poco abuelo cebolleta :D Y sí, yo soy de España.

Comment: No @fedorqui, no me referia a ti como cebolleta, no soy tan pesado como para hacerte eso :), esa frase la usaste tu https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2177/44946

Comment: @Theia jaja ¡ya veo! Un placer ver que me lees :)