# ¿Hay alguna diferencia entre tebeo, historieta y cómic?

Tags: definiciones

En la respuesta dada por Diego a la pregunta [¿De dónde viene la expresión "Qué pesado el abuelo cebolleta"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21478/6915) hoy aprendí la palabra **tebeo**, que por mis tierras es desconocida.

Pues me parece que ya hay demasiadas palabras para referirse a lo mismo, por lo que puedo suponer que *tebeo, cómic* e *historieta* tienen alguna diferencia entre sí.

¿Es así? Es decir, ¿puede que una revista x sea un cómic pero no una historieta?

Comment: Por si ayuda "tebeo" viene de la revista [TBO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBO).

Comment: Y no olvides el término «novela gráfica», que es de moda ahora.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **En España, a la historieta se la ha llamado también tebeo**. Dicho término, puramente local, tiene su origen en la revista [TBO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/TBO), y designa sobre todo a la publicación que contiene historietas, siendo consagrado su uso en la edición de 1968 del Diccionario de la lengua española de la Real Academia Española.
>
> A mediados de los años 70, una parte del medio empezó a defender el uso del término de origen anglosajón comic (escrito al principio sin tilde) para potenciar una historieta de grafismo más realista, pretensiones esteticistas o experimentales y temas considerados más adultos, con abundantes dosis de erotismo, en detrimento de la más habitual en la postguerra, que se dirigía preferentemente a un público infantil.
>
> Fuente:  [La Historieta en España](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historieta_en_Espa%C3%B1a)

Curiosamente la versión en inglés del artículo cita al régimen de Franco y su censura sobre el contenido de estas publicaciones

> After the Spanish Civil War the Franco regime imposed strict censorship in all media, and comics were no exception. As part of this ban, superhero comics were forbidden by the Francoist regime; as a result, comic heroes were based on historical fiction.

Que puede explicar un poco la diferencia en contenido entre comic e historieta (a la distinta nomenclatura para distintas historias).

Yo, personalmente, siempre le he dicho *tebeo* o *historieta* a las publicaciones para público infantil tanto patrias (Mortadelo y Filemón, Zipi y Zape, el botones Sacarino, etc.) como extranjeras (las aventuras de Asterix y Obélix o las de Tintín, de las que también había unas cuántas en mi casa) y *comic* a las aventuras de otros personajes que tenían un corte menos inocente y más serio o agresivo (Batman, Transformers, etc.).

Los términos eran bastante intercambiables (sobre todo cuando era un adulto el que los usaba, porque para ellos todas esas lecturas para los niños caían en el mismo saco). Predominaban  los términos *"comic"* y *"tebeo"* sobre *"historieta"*, y a veces se añadían otros. Las historietas que más me gustaban eran las de Mortadelo y Filemón, que podían estar recogidas en tomos como los *superhumores* o en revistillas como el *[supermortadelo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Mortadelo)*. A veces decíamos simplemente "Me voy a a leer un *Mortadelo*" o "Quiero leer un *Superhumor*".

Comment: Un comentario sobre la censura: efectivamente, los tebeos de superhéroes estaban prohibidos durante el franquismo, aunque al final del mismo podían publicarse, pero con un cartelito en la portada que rezaba "Publicación para adultos". El motivo era que, según la censura, el hecho de que aparecieran unos personajes con poderes sobrehumanos sin ser ángeles podía confundir a los niños. En los tebeos de ficción histórica que mencionas, si ocurría algo sobrenatural, tenía que quedar muy claro que pasaba por intervención divina.

Answer (score 7):

Nada que aportar a la gran respuesta de @Diego. Sólo comentar que, por mi parte, suelo usar:

- «**cómic**» para el género literario;
- «**tebeo**» para el formato físico (la revista);
- «**historieta**» para los capítulos o relatos.

Por ejemplo:

> *Astérix y Obélix* es un **cómic** creado por los autores Goscinny y Uderzo. La primera **historieta** que leí de ellos fue «Las doce pruebas», en un **tebeo** que me compró mi padre cuando tenía 8 años.

Creo que «tebeo» en cuanto a formato es bastante específico: tipo revista, menos de 50 páginas, tapa blanda... Un Superhumor, con sus tapas duras y casi 200 páginas de risa y diversión, yo al menos no lo llamaría un «tebeo»; si acaso, una recopilación de historietas me parece más adecuado.

Como digo, este es mi uso personal de cada término. Si los entendidos los emplean de manera intercambiable o no, ahí ya no entro.

Comment: De hecho ahora uno en España diría que lee un cómic de Batman pero un tebeo de Mortadelo y Filemón, ¿no te parece?