# Algo en que se puede escribir o agregar (Escribible o Agregable)

Tags: solicitud-de-término, adjetivos

Estoy buscando un adjetivo calificativo que indique que se puede agregar o escribir contenido, similar a la palabras en inglés `Writable`.

Resulta que `Escribible` (que se puede escribir) y `Agregable` (que se puede agregar) no parecen ser palabras existentes en español, por lo tanto estoy buscando alternativas.

Lo mismo ocurre con `Insertable` (que se puede insertar), `Adicionable` (que se puede adicionar), `Sumable`, `Añadible`, `Incorporable`, `Redactable`, entre otras.

La palabra `Editable` podría ser la que más se acerca, pero pienso en algo editable como algo que "modifica" un contenido existente, y no necesariamente lo "agrega".

Según el DLE Editar es:

> 1. tr. Publicar por medio de la imprenta o por otros procedimientos una obra, periódico, folleto, mapa, etc.
> 2. tr. Pagar y administrar una publicación.
> 3. tr. Adaptar un texto a las normas de estilo de una publicación.
> 4. tr. Organizar las grabaciones originales para la emisión de un programa de radio o televisión.
> 5. tr. Inform. Abrir un documento con la posibilidad de modificarlo mediante el programa informático adecuado.

En inglés hay varios adjetivos para esto (incluso addable e insertable), pero al traducirlas al español obtengo `Grabable`, que no es lo mismo.

¿Existe en español algún adjetivo para referirse a algo que se puede escribir?

> Este bloc de notas es **"escribible"**.
>
> Este contenido es **"agregable"**

Comment: Escribir no es lo mismo que agregar generalmente, piensa en esto, qué matiz prefieres que predomine.

Comment: Pues a mi me gusta *editable*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Resulta que **Escribible** (que se puede escribir) y **Agregable** (que se puee agregar) no parecen ser palabras existentes en español, por lo tanto estoy buscando alternativas.

"Escribible" es perfectamente válido. La RAE lo confirma en este tuit:

[image]

texto:

> @RAEinforma #RAEconsultas ¿Es correcto usar las palabras **escribible** o pintable?En el diccionario no figuran, en cambio si aparece esgrimible
>
> [Respuesta] #RAEconsultas Son adecuadas desde el punto de vista morfológico. El adj. «pintable» figurará en la próx. ed. del DRAE.

Hace mucho, mucho (mucho!) tiempo (algunos ni habíais nacido <sup>1</sup>), teníamos en informática "floppy discs" con la asombrosa capacidad de almacenamiento de 1.4 MB (más o menos) hasta que llegaron revolucionarios CDs en los que o bien podías escribir (grabar) una única vez o varias (los regrabables). Estos dispositivos se conocían en inglés como "write-once", pero a veces se traducía al español como "escribible una sola vez".

"Editable" tampoco está en el diccionario (aunque sí "evitable"). El diccionario no contiene ni todas las palabras que usamos ni todas las que podemos formar.

Sirva el mencionado tuit como prueba de que puedes usar "escribible" y "agregable" y sobre la que más conviene... eso ya depende del contexto o de algún matiz subjetivo.

---

<sup>1</sup> Historia del [abuelo Cebolleta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21478/5481).

Comment: Es verdad, Diego. Recuerdo inclusive haber oído "reescribible" (o "regrabable") en referencia a los CDs que, si mal no recuerdo, se identificaban con "RW" (rewritable) para indicar la posibilidad de edición o inclusive de borrado y reescritura.

Comment: Esos disquetes eran los que usaba yo en la universidad para guardar las prácticas... luego aparecieron los "pinchos" USB y los repositorios online. Qué rápido se han pasado los últimos 20 años, me cago en la leche...

Comment: ¡Excelente respuesta!, con evidencia y fuentes confiables, como debería ser, recuerdo los disquetes y discos compactos "Writables", pero siempre los vi traducidos como "grabable" o "regrabable", nunca como "escribible".